# Mod of numbers with large exponents [modular order reduction]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I've read about Fermat's little theorem and generally how congruence works. But I can't figure out how to work out these two:

- $13^{100} \bmod 7$
- $7^{100} \bmod 13$

I've also heard of the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242)

$$a \equiv b \,\Rightarrow\, a^k \equiv b^k \pmod n $$

But I don't see how exactly to use that here, because from $13^1 \bmod 7\,$ I get $6$, and $13^2 \bmod 7$ is $1$. I'm unclear as to which one to raise to the $k$'th power here (I'm assuming $k = 100$?)

Any hints or pointers in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Might be useful to recognize that $6=-1 \mod 7$

Comment: @KitterCatter Can you explain it a bit more? (possibly as an answer). Is it derived from $n | (a-b)$?

Comment: I don't know about using fermat (not a mathematician by trade) but it might be helpful to know that the Euler totient function of a prime,$p$ is $p-1$ and that if $a^{\phi(p)} \equiv 1 \mod p$

Comment: Be sure to understand the relation between "mod" as a binary operator vs. ternary relation. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/614944/242) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/121054/242) for more on this. If you only know the operator form you will be *severely* encumbered.

Comment: **See also** $ $  [How do I compute $a^b\,\bmod c$ by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/81228/242) for many approaches.

Comment: $a^k - b^k$ has a factor of $a-b$ thus it holds true

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The formula you've heard of results from the fact that congruences are compatible with addition and multiplication.

The first power  $13^{100}$ is easy: $13\equiv -1\mod 7$, so 
$$13^{100}\equiv (-1)^{100}=1\pmod 7.$$

The second power uses *Lil' Fermat*: for any number $a\not\equiv 0\mod 13$, we have $a^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$, hence 
$$7^{100}\equiv 7^{100\bmod12}\equiv 7^4\equiv 10^2\equiv 9\pmod{13}$$

Comment: Very nice answer! When you reference Lil' Fermat did you mean $a\not\equiv0\mod13$? also it looks like you missed a bracket for the exponent in $a^{12} \equiv 1 \mod 13$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still a little unclear on how you got to $10^2$ from $7^4$?

Comment: $7^4=(7^2)^2=49^2\equiv 10^2$, that's all.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks! It's clear now :)

Comment: @Kitter Catter: Oh! Yes. I should have re-read my answer before posting. I even missed a pair of brackets. It's fixed now. Thanks for pointing the typos!

Comment: Many beginners confuse mod the operator vs relation, and using the above ambiguous notation only exacerbates that problem, Better to use the standard notation, i.e. use `\pmod` not `\mod` in $\TeX$

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: Certainly you're  right. It's only because it's faster typing that I use `\mod`. Fixed it.

Comment: @Improve (!!): Yes , of course. It's getting late here… Thanks for pointing the typo!

Answer (score 12):

**Hint** $\, $ The *key idea* is that any *periodicity* of the exponential map $\,n\mapsto a^n\,$ allows us to use **modular order reduction** on *exponents* as in the results below. We can find *small* periods $\,e\,$ such that $\,a^{\large e}\equiv 1\,$ either by [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) or [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) (or by [Carmichael's lambda generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165728/242)), along with obvious roots of $\,1\,$ such as $\,(-1)^2\equiv 1,$ then use it as below. When $a$ is not coprime to the modulus we can reduce to the coprime case by factoring out their gcd via *mod Distributive law*, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2338836/242) & [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973731/242) and many more [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a242%20mod%20distributive%20law) (or we can generalize the results below to exponents not in the initial preperiodic part of the [rho $(\rho)$ shaped orbit](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3850292/242).) Or we can compute the power mod (coprime) factors of the modulus and then combine them by CRT, e.g. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3839180/242).

**Theorem** $ \ \ $ Suppose that: $\,\ \color{#c00}{a^{\large e}\equiv\, 1}\,\pmod{\! m}\ $ and $\, e>0,\ n,k\ge 0\,$ are integers. Then

$\qquad n\equiv k\pmod{\! \color{#c00}e}\,\Longrightarrow\,a^{\large n}\equiv a^{\large k}\pmod{\!m}\,\ $ [and $\rm\color{#f60}{conversely}$ if $\,a\,$ has order $\,\color{#c00}e\,$ mod $\,m$]

**Proof** $\ $ Wlog $\,n\ge k\,$ so $\,a^{\large n-k}\color{#0a0}{a^{\large k}}\equiv \color{#0a0}{a^{\large k}}\!\!\!\overset{\color{#0a0}{\rm cancel}\!\!}\iff a^{\large n-k}\equiv 1$ $\Leftarrow\!\![\color{#f50}\Rightarrow]\ n\equiv k\pmod{\!e}\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242), where we $\color{#0a0}{{\rm cancelled}\ a^{\large k}}$ using $\,a^{\large e}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, a\,$ is invertible so cancellable (cf. below Remark).

**Corollary** $\ \ \bbox[7px,border:1px solid #c00]{\!\bmod m\!:\,\  \color{#c00}{a^{\large e}\equiv 1}\,\Rightarrow\, a^{\large n}\equiv a^{\large n\bmod \color{#c00}e}}\,\ $ by $\ n\equiv n\bmod e\,\pmod{\!e}$

**Remark** $ $ If modular inverses are known then it is not necessary to restrict to nonnegative powers of $\,a\,$ above since $\,a^{\large e}\equiv 1,\ e> 0\,\Rightarrow\,$  $a$ is invertible by $\,a a^{\large e-1}\equiv 1\,$ so $\,a^{\large -1}\equiv a^{\large e-1}.\,$ As motivation it may help to consider the **additive analog** of  above multiplicative form, namely

**Theorem** $ \ \ $ Suppose that: $\,\ \color{#c00}{e\cdot a \equiv\, 0}\,\pmod{\! m}\ $ and $\, e>0,\ n,k\,$ are integers. Then

$\ \quad n\equiv k\pmod{\! \color{#c00}e}\,\Longrightarrow\,n\cdot a \equiv k\cdot a\pmod{\!m},\, $ and conversely if $\,a\,$ has (+)order $\,\color{#c00}e\,$ mod $\,m$

**Corollary** $\ \ \bbox[7px,border:1px solid #c00]{\!\bmod m\!:\,\  \color{#c00}{e\cdot a\equiv 0}\,\Rightarrow\, n\cdot a\equiv (n\bmod \color{#c00}e)\cdot a}\,\ $ by $\ n\equiv n\bmod e\,\pmod{\!e}$

For example: $\bmod 10\!:\,\ 2\cdot 5 \equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, n\cdot 5\equiv (n\bmod 2)\cdot 5,\,$ a well-known fact about the units digits of multiples of $5,\,$ i.e. it is $\,0\,$ if $\,n\,$ is even, else $\,5.$

For example: $\bmod 12\!:\,\ 3\cdot 8 \equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, n\cdot 8\equiv (n\bmod 3)\cdot 8,\,$ a fact often known to those working rotating $\,8\,$ hour shifts.

The analogy will be clarified if one studies group theory (these are basic facts on *cyclic* groups).

**Remark** $ $ When $\,n < e\,$ then $\,n\bmod e = n\,$ so mod order reduction yields no simplification. Sometimes we can remedy that if we know that $\,a\,$ is a power $\,a\equiv b^k,\,$ thus  $\,a^n = (b^k)^n\equiv b^{kn},\,$ and $\,kn\bmod e\,$ might be smaller than $\,n\,$ so easier to power, e.g. let's consider an example when $\,k = 3,\,$ i.e. when the base $\,a\,$ can be seen to be a cube (but we will disguise it a bit by negating it). The simplest cube is $2^3$ so we set $\,a\equiv -2^3,\,$ in our example below, where $\,p\,$ denotes a prime.

$$\begin {align}\bmod p = 163\!:\, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 155^{54}\equiv\: &(-2^3)^{54}\!\equiv 2^{162}\!\equiv2^{p-1}\equiv 1,\ \ \text{by Fermat;  generally}\\[.2em]
\bmod p=6j\!+\!1\!:\ (p\!-\!8)^{2j}\equiv\: &(-2^3)^{2j}\!\equiv\, 2^{6j}\,\equiv 2^{p-1}\equiv 1
\end{align}\ \ \ $$

The analog of the above for $\,k=2\,$ is essentially the easy part of [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion), e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24181/242).

In any case, we can always [exponentiate by repeated squaring](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/119375/242), which is quite efficient.

Comment: Often it proves simpler to first reduce $\,e\,$ using Euler's Criterion or quadratic reciprocity, e.g. [see here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/24181/242).

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:
$13 = 2\cdot 7-1$ so $13\equiv-1\mod 7$ and therefore $13^{100} \equiv (-1)^{100} \mod 7$

Other one is fairly quick:
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(13) = 12\\ 
\gcd(7,13)=1\\
7^{100}\equiv7^{4} \mod13\\
7\rightarrow10\rightarrow5\rightarrow9
\end{eqnarray}
Probably a nicer way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you please explain how you arrived to step 3? (in your four-step part of the answer), and why you have calculated the gcd(7, 13)?

Comment: Sure. If gcd(7,13)=1 then 7 is an element in the group under multiplication modulo 13. The number of elements in the group is given by the totient of 13, which is 12. Therefore 7^12 = 1 modulo 13. this strips the problem down to figuring out modulo 12. 100 is 4 modulo 12 so we only need to look at 7^4 modulo 13